# ¿java se puede usar swicht o solo catch?

Tags: java, try-catch

¿Que tipo de error tengo en mi código?
¿se necesito usar el switch o solo catch?

Necesito ingresar un valor numérico para:

- calcular la raíz cuadrada?
- calcular el doble del valor numérico?
- calcular el cuadrado del valor ingresado?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner numero = new Scanner(System.in);
               
        double numerico,numerico2;
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese un valor numerico: ");
        numerico=numero.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese un valor numerico: ");
        numerico2 = numero.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Elige la opcion, c-calcular el cuadrado d-calcular el duplo r-calcular la raiz cuadrada:");
        System.out.println(numero);
        
         switch(numero.nextLine()) {
            case "c":
                System.out.println(Math.pow(numerico,numerico2));
                break;
            case "d":
                System.out.println(numerico*2);
                break;
            case "r":
                System.out.println(Math.sqrt(numerico));
                break;
         }
            catch (InputMismatchException ime){
                 System.out.println ("Ingrese unicamente numeros:");
        }
        System.out.println("----------Fin del programa.----------");
                 

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try-catch tiene un uso, switch tiene otro, switch-catch no existe.. Tú cuéntanos qué error te muestra al intentar usar tu código; edita la pregunta y cuéntanos qué error encuentras al ejecutarlo y probarlo. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Ok gracias por la duda, voy revisarlo de nuevo el código.

Comment: ¿Entonces si no puedo usar SWITCH como puedo hacer un menú y elegir una opción de estas 3?

Comment: ¿Porque es necesario tener un SWITCH para elegir que operación quiere hacer en el código, si es raíz,  sacar el cuadrado,  aumentar el doble, el valor que ingrese el usuario?

Comment: switch permite hacer lo que dices querer hacer; que equivale a hacerlo con if-elseif. Lo que te estoy diciendo es que ese código que muestras no va a compilar porque no se entiende de dónde sale ese catch ni para qué lo quieres usar. Estás haciendo `switch{ case... case...} catch { algo }` y esa estructura condicional no existe en java. Switch sí existe pero switch no tiene catch. ¿Se entiende? Si estás copiando y pegando sin entender lo que haces, no te va a funcionar. Corre el código que intentas usar, mira qué error sale y coméntalo acá. Lee la documentación.

Comment: Si revisaras el enlace que te indiqué en el primer comentario, el de Cómo preguntar, verías que parte de ayudarte con un código problemático es que sea un ejemplo verificable. Traes algo que no compila, preguntas por cuál será el error en el código pero no parece que hayas intentado entender qué hace cada línea o tan siquiera intentado correr el programa para ver qué hace

Comment: ok gracias, aunque ya lo estoy revisando y cree otro código y tengo el problema que no me deja seleccionar la opción, pero el código si funciona bien.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String operaciones;
    double numero;
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    
    try{
    System.out.println("Ingrese un valor numerico: ");
   numero = Double.parseDouble(lector.nextLine());
    
    String operacion = "Elige una operacion: \n"
            + "c-calcular el cuadrado \nd-calcular el duplo \nr-calcular la raiz";
    System.out.println(operacion);
    
       operaciones = lector.nextLine();
    
    switch(operaciones){
        case "c":
           System.out.println("Resultado del cuadrado " + Math.pow (numero,2));
            break;
          case "d":
          System.out.println("El resultado del cuadrado es: "+(numero*2));
          break;
          case "r":
          System.out.println("El resultado de la raiz es:"+Math.sqrt(numero));
          break;
          default:
              System.out.println("Esta opcion no existe.");
    }
    }
                catch( NumberFormatException ime){
                System.out.println("Ingrese unicamente numeros.");
                }
          catch(ArithmeticException ae){
              System.out.println("Imposible dividir por cero");
          }
    System.out.println("-------FIN DEL PROGRAMA-------");
     
    }
    }
```

Listo gente ya lo termine haciendo, gracias por aclararme dudas.

Comment: Enserio tenías todo el crédito de mi respuesta??? 

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, aunque a lo ultimo el profesor me termino ayudando, y es por eso que lo pude completar.

Comment: Si claro se nota en la respuesta -1

Answer (score 0):

Ok mira, para que no te enredes tanto observa esto. Agrega una variable `String op` a tu código.

```java
double numerico,numerico2;
String op="";
```

posteriormente vamos a asignar el valor a la variable `op`

```java
op = numero.nextLine() //pasamos el valor de entrada a la variable
```

y ahora bien modificamos el switch para que todo quede bien

```java
switch(op) {
    case "c":
        System.out.println(Math.pow(numerico,numerico2));
        break;
    case "d":
        System.out.println(numerico*2)
        break;
    case "r":
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(numerico));
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Opcion invalida, ingrese únicamente las mencionadas");
}
```

*Nota: Ten en cuenta que únicamente vas a tener errores en los números, pues si ingresan texto en estos te va a generar un error, solo ahí debes usar `try-catch`.*

Ejemplo:

```java
System.out.println("Ingrese un valor numerico: ");
try{
    numerico=numero.nextDouble();
}catch(Exception e){//error del tipo InputMismatchException
    System.out.println("Error ingrese valor numerico!");
}
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.

Comment: Ok gracias, voy a revisarlo con mi código.